# Creating product label with Amazon MWS API

Tags: amazon-mws

I can't seem to find the answer to this, I want to be able to add an item to a inbound shipment and then print the label, I have found the info below

http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_UK/fba_guide/FBAGuide_LabelItems1x1.html

Point 2 says "Use the FulfillmentNetworkSKU returned in Step 1 to create a label for your item"

But I can't any call to use FulfillmentNetworkSKU to generate the label.

Anyone any idea's ?

Thanks

Darren

Answer (score 1):

From what I have found, AZ don't have any method apart from the web interface for creating labels from the FNSKU, but the actual barcode is is Code128A encoded, so all you need to do is get the FNSKU when adding an item to your shipping que, then Encode it to a Barcode.

There are a number of free classes on the net to do the job.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like they have left those specific instructions out.  Currently we use Seller Central to create our shipment plans, but eventually will use MWS.  Is it maybe [GetUniquePackageLabels](https://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/fba_inbound/FBAInbound_GetUniquePackageLabels.html) that you call?

In any event, I would contact MWS support and ask this question.  They will come back to you pretty quickly with an answer.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I will have a look in to the call, I am struggling to find contact details for MWS Support, would you know what they are ?